# Flutter App Stuck on Launcher Screen Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am running my flutter app on physical device, but it gets stuck on launcher screen. The run console doesn't show any error except these two lines:

```
I/flutter ( 5947): Observatory listening on ************************************
D/FlutterLocationService( 5947): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 5947): Binding to location service.
```

But when I run on Emulator it runs fine. What can be issue. I have added the permissions for internet access and location as well. Still not working

I dont what to check for this as it is showing no error !!! just getting stuck

Flutter Doctor results:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: It might not be the issue, but emulators mock or take location from your laptop. For Android devices, permissions must be requested before use and not just listed in the AndroidManifest. Does your app require the Locations permission, and if so, are you requesting this permission as soon as your app launches? If it needs a permission it has not been granted by a user, Android apps will not work correctly.

Comment: @RoboBear okay i will check on it !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this was a problem for not getting the permissions. Now you have to explicity ask for permission in flutter. Just adding in Android Manifest does not work. I use [Permission Handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin and added this code And the error goes away

**Edit:** Now that Android 11 update has come, most of devices are being stuck at Native Splash Screen for infinity. This issue is also reported on github as well [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82520)

Comment: What code did you add? I'm already using permission_handler.
My app stuck when I'm try to build in release mode, in debug mode it's ok, maybe you know what's happening? 

My android is 11, it means that all the android 11 can't run the app?

Comment: haven't tested a release app on android 11, but in debug mode apps were not working mostly in vivo smart phones @Katekko

Comment: @Katekko Did you find the cause for this issue? I'm experiencing the same. Works in debug mode but not in release. And I'm already requesting permission explicitly.